# Connect to PHP Json Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a question for you
when i comment this line , flutter connects to php and i have no error.

....................

//List jsonResponse = convert.decode(response.body);
.............
but when this line not commented, flutter does not connect to php

E/flutter ( 4177): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Utgqo.jpg)

Comment: `Unexpected character (at character 1)` in `response.body` - is your answer ...

Comment: Add the raw response that you're getting from the API JSON.

Comment: Hey, Are you using a free server like 000webhost or infinity free, because this error is common to free servers